# Modelling the Oregonator

Tags: kinetics, theoretical-chemistry

Assuming this is the correct place for a post like this, I need to write a piece of code to show the oscillations in the [Oregonator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oregonator). I have successfully done so for the [Brusselator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brusselator), but have been unable to find the appropriate rate constants and starting concentrations for the [Oregonator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oregonator).

Any help or information on a better place to post this would be appreciated.

Comment: see Field & Noyes, J. Chem. Phys. v60,p1877,1974 for the original.  Scott,  ' Oscillations Waves and Chaos in Chemical Kinetics' (publ OUP) gives the scheme, rate constants and reduced variables to use in this scheme.

Comment: I am not able to access these papers or find a copy of this book online. If possible, could you please provide me with the starting concentrations and the necessary rate constants. Thanks.

Comment: yes but much later on today

Comment: I believe [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fa74/3e39198cfc0c58f46ac63abb70fe8cd030d6.pdf) is the paper [PDF].