# How to model the Belousov-Zhabotinsky (BZ) (in Maple)

Tags: kinetics, stoichiometry, theoretical-chemistry, software

I need to model the Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction (or a different oscillating one). I found out about the Oregonator and the Brusselator reaction and now I want to model them in Maple (or similar software). In this [post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97407/modeling-belousov-zhabotinsky-reaction-using-ordinary-differential-equations?newreg=5b6c22ec5b8047179f394b6a13e0008c) the rate equations are given. On [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Oregonator) the rate equations are scaled (I do not know what that means), but I still don't have clue how to model this. I have very basic knowledge of rate equations and modelling reactions (it is a project at the end of secondary school). I do know how to differentiate and find primitives of a lot of functions if that's needed.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me how scientists use rate equations and if someone could show me how to enter the Oregonator (and/or Brusselator) in Maple of similar software. Preferably also that I can change the starting concentrations (and the temperature if that's possible).

Many thanks!

Comment: Meh, you just need a script written in language of specific software. To write one you need to learn a bit about it's syntax, and, if you write it properly, soft is gonna numerically solve the equations for you.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118675/modelling-the-oregonator

Comment: Use function [`dsolve`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve). Take a look at the examples. All you need to provide is the vector field — that is, the right-hand side of each differential equation — and the initial conditions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks, my laptop automatically changed it bc it didn't recognise the word.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now looking for the needed rate constants and concentrations. I'm also exploring the dsolve. If a new question arises, I'll let you know.

Comment: Answering one's own question is encouraged. When you are done with your project, please consider posting an answer here, with graphs and Maple code, so that others can build on your work and do not have to start from zero.